# Indentation Error, doesn't match indentation level. Did not use spacing

Tags: python

```
#When user selects 1, and the silver isn't right and gold isn't left, "the door remains locked" message appears. Otherwise, the door opens and the program ends
elif (selection == 1):
    if (silver == 2 and gold == 1):
        print (done)
        break
    print ("The door remains stubbornly locked!\n \nRoom: Entrance Hallway \n------------")
```

Above is my code. Below is the error I am getting:

```
File "rooms.py", line 84
    elif (selection == 1):
                         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I am pretty sure I did not use extra spacing either.

Comment: The first line uses spaces for indentation, the next three lines use tabs, and the last line uses spaces. Use only one or the other, not both.

Comment: There's more missing here, show the surrounding code, or is that meant to be an `if` not an `elif`

Comment: As it stands this is unanswerable. Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, you are most likely mixing up tabs and spaces.
The best option would be to replace your tabs with spaces (or vice versa) using the search and replace function of whatever text editor your are using.

For example in vim you can use the regular expression:

```
:%s/^I/    /g
```

where ^I (ctrl+I) is the equivalent of tab. This particular example replaces all tabs with 4 spaces

You'll then want to make sure that you are using the same number of spaces for each indent